# Efficient Method/Algorithm to Compute the P-adic Ordinal of a Positive Integer

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am currently writing my master's thesis at Cal Poly Pomona, and am currently investigating the ruler sequence for a prime base.

The ruler sequence for base $2$ is : $0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,...$ that is the power of 2 which strictly divides a positive integer $n$.
Since my research involves a more general form (usually prime base) we can make the appropriate generalization:

$$p^{r_p(n)}||n$$

The first thing to note is that $r_p(n)=ord_p(n)$ where $ord_p(n)$ is the the p-adic oridinal or valuation of $n$ (Since I am also considering the order of $n$ modulo $p^k$, I want to stay away from the latter notation).

Now I am currently using a rather inefficient method to calculate $r_2(n)$, but it is concise; meaning that I can use a spread sheet program to rapidly output tables for analysis. The formula is as follows:
$$r_p(n)=\log_p(\gcd(n,p^{\lfloor\log_p(n)\rfloor})),$$

The above is efficient enough to find values for small $n$, but in examining $r_p(n^a-1)$ I run into issues involving the efficiency of my formula. Note: $a$ is a positive integer and $n>1$.

I was wondering if anyone knew of, or could point me in the direction of, a more efficient, and ideally direct, method to compute the p-adic ordinal of $n^a-1$ for relatively small values of $n$.

Comment: I don't know whether this is of help: I've worked with that problem myself and made a little "algebra" with it in the pdf-file linked at "Mersenne numbers, cyclic subgroups ... " at my math-site http://go.helms-net.de/math/index.htm Perhaps it gives at least some more idea/suggestion for the formalization of your problem and then a better implementation of the computation (I do things always in Pari/GP and sometimes in Excel)

Comment: Hmm, more concrete to your concern of actual computation: if n is "small", as you say, why not simply do repeated trial division by the interesting $p$? In a spreadsheet like excel you can assign a visual-basic routine to any cell, and in visual basic it is easy to program such a function for n less than, say, 2^32 or the like. Also, what size has $a$ usually in your problem?

Comment: I'll look into that. Currently $a$ is small under 50, but compounded with $n$ up to 1000 I run into the limits of either excel or its GCD function. I usually run in much quicker than either of those two limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following method is probably pretty well known. I’ll use the notation $v_p(n)$ instead of your $\text{ord}_p(n)$.

Of course you know that if $p|n$ then $v_p(n^\alpha-1)=0$ for all positive $\alpha$, so we don’t need to worry about numbers $n$ divisible by $p$. For a number $n$ prime to $p$, though, I’ll call $\omega_p(n)$ the smallest positive power of $n$ for which $n^\omega\equiv1\pmod p$. It’s a divisor of $p-1$, and all divisors of $p-1$ occur. Now you see that if $\omega_p(n)$ does not divide $\alpha$, then $v_p(n^\alpha-1)=0$. So we need only look at multiples of $\omega_p(n)$.

Next fact, easily shown for $p\ne2$, and necessarily modified for $p=2$, is that if $v_p(N-1)\ge1$, then $v_p(N^p-1)=1+v_p(N-1)$.

And the final fact is that if $m$ is prime to $p$ and $v_p(N-1)\ge1$, then $v_p(N^m-1)=v_p(N-1)$.

Let’s do an example, $n=7$ and $p=5$. In this case, $\omega_5(7)=4$, and since $7^4=2401$, we have $v_5(7^4-1)=2$. Now we need only ask for $v_5(7^{4\beta}-1)$, that is for values of $\alpha=4\beta$. Now write $\beta=5^tu$, and see that $v_5(7^{4\beta}-1)=2+t$.

Comment: Cool, I have a conjecture that for $a$ a positive integer, $p$ an odd prime, and $n\equiv 1 \pmod p$, then $r_p(n^a-1)=r_p(n-1)+r_p(a)$. I have complete versions for $p=2$ and $p=3$, and am attempting to generalize this for any prime and any $n$. I'll see what I can do with what you've written.

Comment: Your conjecture is on the mark. Good luck!